# How can i put condition in relation in laravel?

Tags: laravel, model, relation, data-retrieval, wherehas

I have **File** model that it store my images, and i have **shop** model, the shop can have many images and in shop model i wrote this code:

```
public function Files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('system\models\file', 'attachment_id');
    }
```

and i want retrieve shop model with it's images, now my question is how can i put where condition in relation. my code for retrieve shop model is:

```
$shop = Shop::where('id', $id)->with('ShopType', 'User', 'Files')->get();
```

**note:** i need to put 2 condition for relation that one of theme set in Files method that call attachment_id and my second condition is attachment_type
please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use constraining-eager-loads:

```
$shop = Shop::with(['ShopType','User', 'Files'=>function ($query)use($id)
{
query->where('id', $id);
}
])->get();
```

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
public function all() { 
     return $this->hasManyThrough('ShopType', 'User', 'Files');
}
```

and then

```
$shop = Shop::with('all')->where('id',$id)->get();
```

Comment: How can i add it in this code: ```$shop = Shop::where('id', $id)->with('ShopType', 'User', 'Files')->get();```

Comment: You can use  this syntax in Model
`public function all() {
return $this->hasManyThrough('ShopType', 'User', 'Files'); 
}` and then 
`$shop = shop::with('all')->where('id',$id)->get();`